# How come I can't use CSS this way?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I wanted to create a web app using ReactJS.  I got the `bootstrap` working but now I want the `CSS` to work.  Why isn't my method valid in doing what my `CSS` is trying to do?

Here's my `index.html` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
     <title>My website</title>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.js"></script>
     <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.6.16/browser.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="firstBar"></div>
    <script type="text/babel" src="index.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Here's my `index.css` file:

```
#portfolio {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Here's my `index.js` file:

```
var TitleBar = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return(
      <div className="container">
        <button id="portfolio" type="button" className="btn btn-primary">Portfolio</button>
        <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary">About</button>
        <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary">Contact</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<TitleBar />, document.getElementById('firstBar'));
```

Comment: maybe because you're using `#portfolio` instead of `.portfolio`?

Comment: @MichaelCoker I changed it, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Does anything in your style sheet work?  Or is it just that one rule?

Comment: Isn't the 2nd `className` on your button overwriting the `className="portfolio"` ? Why not just have `className="portfolio btn btn-primary"`

Comment: @deefour you're right, I had 2 `className`'s.  In my edit, I changed it to ID as well as the CSS to go along with it, it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using className twice. It will work if you put the portfolio class in the other className.

```
var TitleBar = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return(
      <div className="container">
        <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary portfolio">Portfolio</button>
        <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary">About</button>
        <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary">Contact</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<TitleBar />, document.getElementById('firstBar'));
```

http://codepen.io/justdan/pen/JEyYvQ?editors=1010

Comment: Right on and you're welcome =). Care to give me a +1 for that, please?

Comment: Sure, no problem.

Comment: Thanks dude! I went ahead and upvoted you also so you could break even for your question also =)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's because your CSS references the ID `#portfolio` instead of the class `.portfolio`. The `#` in front of the name means the element is an ID, and the `.` means the element is a class.

Comment: @chompy what's the rendered HTML? And do you have any errors in the browser console?

Comment: No errors at all.  I just want to see my CSS in action on my first button

Comment: use f12 to see what style rules are being applied, what is being generated, and what is being loaded on the network.